# wpdb::update cannot update field named 'active'

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I try to update field named 'active' in MySQL and every time I do this `wpdb::update` change my value to `0`. Do anybody know why? Below I paste some example.

here is create code to DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_mdbaffiliate_applications` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`active` CHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

here is how I create row:

```
    public function __construct() {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->show_errors = true;
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
    }
    $this->wpdb->insert('wp_mdbaffiliate_applications', array(
        'user_id'       => get_current_user_id(),
        'active'        => '0'
    ));
```

here is my update query:

```
    $status = $this->wpdb->update('wp_mdbaffiliate_applications', array(
        'active' => 'awaiting'
    ), array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id()
    ));
    $mySpecificCase = array(
        $this->wpdb->last_query,
        $this->wpdb->last_result,
        $this->wpdb->last_error,
    );
    var_dump($mySpecificCase);
    var_dump($status);
```

here is what it always return (no matter if value is 'awaiting' or 'umbrella'):

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(78) "UPDATE `wp_mdbaffiliate_applications` SET `active` = 0 WHERE `user_id` = 33584" [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> string(0) "" }
int(0)
```

and if i change `active` to anything else (for example status) it works and return:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(87) "UPDATE `wp_mdbaffiliate_applications` SET `status` = 'awaiting' WHERE `user_id` = 33584" [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> string(0) "" } 
int(1)
```

When i use this:

```
$this->wpdb->query("UPDATE `wp_mdbaffiliate_applications` SET `active` = 0 WHERE `user_id` = 33584")
```

it works fine.

Comment: $post_id= get_current_user_id();
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_mdbaffiliate_applications SET 
    active = 'awaiting'
    WHERE user_id = '$post_id'");

Comment: try this also 
                 $post_id= get_current_user_id();
 $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_mdbaffiliate_applications SET 
    active = 'awaiting'
    WHERE user_id = '$post_id'"));

Comment: I said it works :) you must have misunderstood me. I don't have a problem with that (i changed `active` to `status` and everything is ok), just thought it interesting. And I'm curious why `active` didn't work

Comment: ok my bad i did'nt read the full question.

Comment: @TechnoDeviser your `wpdb::prepare` example should look like this: 
`$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_mdbaffiliate_applications SET active = 'awaiting' WHERE user_id =%d", array( $post_id ))); `